# How to configure Azure load balancer NAT rules for multiple VMs?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. I created two Linux VMs in same virtual network (same subnet)
2. These two VMs don't any public IP address. For security, I don't want to have any public IP associated with them.
3. However, I need ssh into those VMs. Since, they just have private IP and not public IP addresses, I am setting up a load balancer with public IP.
4. Now I am using inbound NAT rules to redirect SSH traffic to those VMs.
5. When I add first NAT rules, it gives me a choice to choose VM to where I want to redirect the traffic to. So all is good so far.

**However, when I try to add one more NAT rule, portal UI doesn't provide me any option to choose other VM. It adds the rule against the same VM.**

Is there anything am I missing? Is it supposed to work differently? I also tried add multiple virtual machines to backend pool. That also doesn't let me add more than one VM.

Should I put two VMs in VM Scaleset or Availability set?

[image: Azure inbound NAT rule - Azure portal UI]

Comment: As I discovered on this article https://www.petri.com/azure-arm-vms-availability-sets, When you load balance or NAT ARM virtual machines, you are forced into using availability sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure, we can use Load balancer with **a single standalone** VM, also we can use Load Balancer with **multiple VMs in an availability set**.

If you want to use Load Balancer NAT to multiple VMs, we should **re-create** VMs in **same** availability set.

In Azure Resource Module, we can delete VMs and keep the VHD, then use PowerShell to create VMs in the same availability set.  (Re-create)